# Localize the content of a Link Module in DNN

Tags: localization, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I am using the default Links module to create a list of links in DotNetNuke.

So I have added the module inside the page and gave a title of "Links". Then I have added two links pointing to page of my site (Link 1 and Link 2).

Now I would like to translate the page and its modules to another language. I have been able to translate everything on the page except the title of every link inside the module (Link 1/Link 2).

Is there a way to accomplish this? Am I using these features in the correct way?

Generally speaking, is there a way to localize DNN standard modules?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're doing to localize this page/module? Are you using DNN Core localization or a third party solution? What version of DNN are you using?

Comment: I am using DNN 5.06 Community Edition. I am using Core localization. What do you mean by elaborate what I am doing? I have tried to localize the page using the standard features of the platform and so have been able to translate content of the HTML module in the page and title of the Link Module. Anyway I have not found a way to translate the content of the Link module

Comment: I just wanted to find out if you were using core stuff or third party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late but might I suggest the [ealo text html module](http://ealo.codeplex.com). This might be the solution

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will check it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

With core localization features (as of 5.6) - when you localize a page you are effectively making a copy - and the intent is that you localize the text in the module on the second page manually - meaning that you physically update the second links module's text/links etc.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I am going to evaluate a third party product for this reason. :)